# In browser stack local, what is the difference between '--proxy-host' and '--local-proxy-host'?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, proxy, protractor, browserstack

BS has a couple of articles talking about proxy/firewall.

1) https://www.browserstack.com/local-testing#modifiers

2) https://www.browserstack.com/downloads/Local-Testing-Internals.pdf

In reference 2, it seems that the only proxy/firewall scenario BS people have in mind is: the firewall exist between BS local (and internal server) and BS infrastructure.

Then in reference 1, i am totally confused by:

```
BrowserStackLocal.exe  --key ACCESS_KEY --proxy-host <proxy_host> --proxy-port <proxy_port>
BrowserStackLocal.exe --key ACCESS_KEY --local-proxy-host <browsermob_proxy_host> --local-proxy-port <browsermob_proxy_port> --local-proxy-user <proxy_username> --local-proxy-pass <proxy_password>
```

When to use one or the other?

Also I do not understand in reference 1, what is the difference when they talk about 'behind proxy' and 'behind firewall or VPN'. Say I am testing within a corporate environment protected by firewall, then what is 'behind a proxy'?

Would someone clarify it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three cases that can happen.

1. You have a simple HTTP Proxy (Proxy should whitelist traffic to *.browserstack.com)

   BrowserStackLocal.exe  --key ACCESS_KEY --proxy-host  --proxy-port
2. You have a MITM proxy and also can directly access the internet(browserstack.com)

.`/BrowserStackLocal.exe --key ACCESS_KEY --local-proxy-host <browsermob_proxy_host> --local-proxy-port <browsermob_proxy_port>`

In this case we don't honour local-proxy-host and try to directly connect to browserstack.com
All other traffic goes through your proxy.

3. You have a MITM proxy and also cannot directly access the internet(browserstack.com) as well.

`BrowserStackLocal.exe --key ACCESS_KEY --proxy-host <proxy_host> --proxy-port <proxy_port> --local-proxy-host <browsermob_proxy_host> --local-proxy-port <browsermob_proxy_port>`

should whitelist *.browserstack.com as well. In this case your internal traffic will go through your MITM proxy and browserstack.com related request will go through your proxy_host param

Also i would suggest to reach out to browserstack Support for such queries.
Disclaimer : I work at browserstack.

Comment: I've added the proxy and run the binary. It seems to connect to www.browerstack.com successfully. But my IE is having problem opening remote browser, and my selenium test cannot connect to hub-cloud.browserstack.com. Do you know what can be the problem?

Comment: Reach out to browserstack support. They did be happy to help.
https://www.browserstack.com/contact